# In AngularJS, how do I optionally wrap item in a link

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a person with a name and an optional home page. How do I optionally wrap their name in an anchor tag?

```
<ul ng-repeat='person in people'>
  <li>
    <a href="{{person.website}}">
      {{person.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or in the case where `person.website` is nil

```
<ul ng-repeat='person in people'>
  <li>
    {{person.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In rails I would use the method `<%= link_to_unless person.website.blank?, seller.name, seller.website %>`

How do I do this in AngularJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the following function to your scope:

```
$scope.linkToUnless = function(condition, label, href) {
    return condition ? '<a href="'+href'+">'+label+'</a>' : label;
};
```

or you could rework your HTML to something like:

```
<ul ng-repeat='person in people'>
  <li>
    <a href="{{person.website}}" ng-if="person.website">
      {{person.name}}
    </a>
    <span ng-if="!person.website">
        {{person.name}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*(just a note inspired by OP's comment, `ng-if` is available only since anugular 1.1.5; for older versions use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` instead*

or you could write a custom directive and use it like:

```
<link-to-if href="person.website" label="person.name" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the three possibilities. As an angular novice, I am not sure which one to choose.

Comment: I would go for the second one since it is quick, easy and still gives you an option to easily use more angular directives in your HTML

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept this answer if it answers your question :)

Comment: I spent way too much time trying to get ng-if working before I realized ng-if was introduced in version 1.1.5 and stable release version is 1.0.8.